# Can I delete .com.google.Chrome files?

Tags: internal-storage

There are many .com.google.Chrome files in my Download folder (How do you want to open this file?)  Is it okay to delete them?

Answer (score 5):

It's safe to delete them. They are caches or incomplete downloads from unknown versions of Google Chrome (judging by name).

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can delete `com.google.chrome` files they are just caches file or sometimes some are files are also present. but you can delete them. They doesn't creates any problem.

Personally i also delete many of com.* folders. It doesn't create any problem for me till now.